# How do you automatically look up Microsoft teams app tenant id

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

We have created a Microsoft Teams tab app with bot integration that we want to distribute to various organizations either manually or via an App Store. In summary,

1. We created Tabs App with Microsoft Bot using node.js botbuilder package.
2. We provided zip archive to another organization (another tenant Id).
3. Organization uploaded our app using Microsoft Teams Admin panel and approved permission in Permission tabs.

Question is how can we receive the tenant id from the organization we are deploying to without asking their admins to go to Azure Active Directory and look it up. Once provided, the graph api and the multi tenant bot does work fine. We are trying to avoid asking their admin to provide us the tenant id and want to retrieve it automatically upon the app being uploaded or on startup.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to get the tenant id is from the [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) you are provided by logging in to your app.  Look for the 'tid' value.

I'm assuming you are talking about stream lining the company wide admin consent for your application.

What you can do is have a web site that a customer's admin can log into (using standard Microsoft OAuth interactive flow).  You can then pull the Tenant ID from the access token and then run through the [Microsoft consent process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent?pivots=portal).  Once consent process redirected back to your web site, you can do your own customer onboarding if required.

Comment: Thank you Shane. We don't use oAuth for users. Once granted access, we use a proprietary login mechanism. So in essence, another way to ask the question is, can we call into some api, once granted permissions by the admin, in order to get the tenant id?

Comment: I assume you are using application permissions, in which case there isn't any way.  You need to know this up front.  Which is why I was saying to create your own web site to onboard / setup a customer so you can collect/populate your own setup through this onboarding process.  The customer needs to consent your application anyway, having it under your control/setup seems like a better way to go.

Comment: Shane, can you provide a flow? We create a page, then ask the user to authenticate using their AD credentials and then how do we upload our app and have them approve? Do we redirect to some Microsoft page?

Comment: I forgot you are a teams tab app.  Enable SSO to get the current user token for your app.  Then pull the tenant id out of the token.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview

Comment: So enable SSO for the admin user only, have him go through his own auth, then redirect to us or redirect to the admin consent page (if there's one). Sorry, trying to understand the flow. Step by step. Don't need a full writeup, just steps so I could understand

Comment: No, for your teams tab app.  When a teams client loads your teams app page into teams you can get teams to give you a token for the current logged in user.  You can use it to access the graph api on behalf of that user.  Or you can use it to pull the tid out of it.

Comment: Thanks, but how do we only do it for the admin and not ask regular users to log in?

Comment: It looks like when our app is installed, the bot contains an even membersadded that includes the tenant id. This link also confirms it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/conversation-messages so I don't think we need what you suggested.

Comment: The user has to login when they run the teams client.  When SSO is enabled you can get a token for that already logged in user from teams in your teams tab app.  So it's "always" logged in so you don't need to worry about logging in...  Now you are talking about a bot server, which is not a team tab client.  Yes, when a user joins a bot conversation thier user details are available.  But for a user to "join" the bot they have to provide a access token... so they have to log in...  Which ever way you come at this there must be a logged in user to start this.